# How to prevent resource loading of unattached elements in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, webkit

I'm working on Chrome extension and I have following problem:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="a.png">';
```

What happens now is that Chrome tries to load the "a.png" resource, even If I don't attach the "div" element to document. Is there a way to prevent it?

_In the extension I need to get data from a site that doesn't provide any API, so I have to parse the whole HTML to get the necessary data. Writing my own simple HTML parser could be tricky so I would rather use the native HTML parser. However, in Chrome when I put the whole source code to some temporary non-attached element (so it would get parsed and I could filter the necessary data), ale the images (and possibly other resources) start to load as well, causing higher traffic or (in case of relative paths) lots of errors in console. _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the resources from being loaded, you'll need to create your *Node* in an entirely new [*#document*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document). You can use [`document.implementation.createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument) for this.

```
var dom = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(); // make new #document
// now use this to..
var myDiv = dom.createElement('div');  // ..create a <div>
myDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="a.png">'; // ..parse HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delay parsing/loading html by storing it in non-standard attribute, then assigning it to innerHtml, "when the time comes":

```
myDiv.setAttribute('deferredHtml', '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Single_apple.png">');

global.loadDeferredImage = function() {
    if(myDiv.hasAttribute('deferredHtml')) {
      myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.getAttribute('deferredHtml');
      myDiv.removeAttribute('deferredHtml');
    }
};

... onclick="loadDeferredImage()"
```

I created jsfiddle illustrating this idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/CbCst/3/